# Does -* have any special meaning in regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I have string as:

```
String str = Hello+Bye-see*Go/ok
```

Now, I wanted to split based on `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`. So I did:

```
str.split("[+-*/]");
```

But this failed, throwing an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 3
[+-*/]
   ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2594)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2507)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2030)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2313)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2355)
```

Then I changed the regex to:

```
str.split("[-+*/]");
```

And it works perfectly fine ! So I was wondering if `-*` has any special meaning? What did I do wrong in the regex `[+-*/]`?

Comment: Read the `Pattern` javadoc. `-` has a special meaning inside `[]`.

Comment: Yes it does , but if there is no common range for the two characters that appear around it wont it ignore the special meaning? Or am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: FYI, added explanation as to why the reverse, `[*-+]`, would be valid! :)

Comment: @Destructor If you're asking whether `[z-a]` should be treated as looking for three characters, `z`, `-`, or `a`, because there is no range `z-a` ... I can understand why that might make sense, but a rule like that would be too confusing and too likely to cause incorrect programs to give confusing results (instead of throwing exceptions).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**A. Where is the Error?**

The problem is not `-*`. The problem is that in a `[character class]`, the hyphen `-` has special meaning. For instance, in `[a-z]`, it means *all characters ranging from a to z*. Therefore, when you have `+-*` in your character class, we are looking for characters ranging from `+` (ASCII 43) to `*` (ASCII 42). Not valid, hence the error. Technically, as @Pshemo writes in a comment, Java doesn't use indexes of characters based on ASCII but based on Unicode Table. But since the 128 first ASCII character points are the same in Unicode, the result is the same.

You need to either escape the hyphen like so `\-` or, as you have observed, throw the `-` at the front (or back) of your class, where it does not indicate a character range:

```
[-+*/]
```

Therefore, in a split (using the "at the back" version for variety):

```
String[] result = your_original_string.split("[+*/-]");
```

**B. But `[*-+]` would be valid!!! (ASCII 42 to 43)**

If you reverse the `+` and the `*`, you have a valid ASCII range (42 to 43). Of course there's no point doing so, since (i) there are no characters in the middle and (ii) that would confuse my dog.

**C. Does `-*` have special meaning?**

It does, but not in a character class. Outside a character class, that means *match a hyphen, zero or more times*.

Comment: whats weird is that if you read the documentation it says that the additional meaning is ignored whenever there is not a common range interpretation.  So either +-* is a common ASCII range, or we have different understandings of the word common =P

Comment: Well as said above I thought +-* is not a common range representation! Well I will keep this in mind! and avoid having "-" in between two characters!

Comment: @AdamYost What documentation are you referring to?  (I don't see it in the `Pattern` javadoc.)  In any case, the word `common` probably doesn't mean what you think it means, but I can't tell without seeing the phrase in context.

Comment: This makes perfect sense!! I should have looked at the ASCII values!! I saw that *-+ works , so assumed wrong!! Thanks a lot @zx81!

Comment: @AdamYost Haven't looked at the doc, but isn't it lovely that `[*-+]` is valid?

Comment: While I like how this answer explain things there is one detail which can be improved. Java doesn't use indexes of characters based on ASCII but based on Unicode Table. This detail is important since there are [two ASCII tables](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/files/ascii.htm) and indexes of characters from second one are not the same as indexes in Unicode Table.

Comment: @zx81 Actually there is night now in Poland so you should say "dobry wieczór", "dzień dobry" is during day :)

Comment: @Pshemo Ha, the only other phrase I remember is `tura godjyna?`, I should have said that first. :)

Comment: Yes that would help :) BTW second form would be pronounced like "dobry viechor".